# Get Radio selection value and used in another element - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a table generated using ng-repeat and use a radio button as a column. When the user selects, I fetch some data. Now I have to move to another page with that value of the selected radio button in the url.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="row in values">
<td>
<input type="radio" ng-click="someMethod()">
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<span ng-click="goTo('someurl'+{{radioValue}})">Click Me</span>
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need `ng-model` (the same for all radio buttons) and `value`, best: `ng-value` (that contains different values for your selection, e.g. each `row` element). Binding `ng-model` is slightly tricky on its own, so I did it with `$parent`, but feel free to modify it.

Here is a simple demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.values = ["/home", "/about", "/contacts"];
  //$scope.radioValue = $scope.values[0]; // default, otherwise check for undefined
  $scope.goTo = function(x) {
    if (x) {
      console.log("goTo:", 'someurl' + x);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in values">
      <td>
        <input type="radio" 
               ng-model="$parent.radioValue" 
               ng-value="row" 
               ng-click="someMethod()"> {{row}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button ng-click="goTo(radioValue)">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your radio buttons have the same `ng-model` attribute.

An example taken from the [AngularJS docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red">
    Red
</label><br/>
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue">
    Green
</label><br/>
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="blue">
    Blue
</label><br/>
<tt>color = {{color.name | json}}</tt><br/>
```

Then your ng-click `goTo` should do the trick.